# jquery limit each to one div

Tags: jquery, limit

Im trying to find and count all input fields inside a div, and disable a button if any are empty. However there are several divs with the same class. I only need the input fields for one. Tried a dozen things but it aint working. It either counts all input fields on the page or none.

```
 function submitDisable(){
    counter = 0;
    $('.shipdiv input').each(function(){
    if( $(this).val() == ''){
    $(this).css("background-color","#ff0000");
    $(this).closest('.shipdiv').find('#button-submit').prop('disabled', true);
    counter++;
}
    if( $(this).val() != ''){
    $(this).css("background-color","");
    counter-1;
}

    if(counter == "0"){
    $(this).closest('.shipdiv').find('#button-submit').prop('disabled', false);
    }
});
```

}

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
$('.shipdiv').click(submitDisable);
});
```

I tried: `$(this, 'input')` using `find();` using `children();` hope anyone undestands and can help me. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to make sure the scope of your search is set to the div which was clicked. At the moment you are finding all divs with the class `shipdiv` and all `input` fields underneath. Update your function to call `.find()` on the clicked div, `$(this)`:

```
function submitDisable(){
    counter = 0;
    $(this).find('input').each(function(){
        ..
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if( $('.shipdiv input[value=""]').length>0 )
{
    $('.shipdiv input:first').closest('.shipdiv').find('#button-submit').prop('disabled', true);
}
```